# The python program should take links from the document line by line and return text, but an error occurs

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

program itself:

```
import numpy as np
import requests
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

x = open('doc.txt','r')
a = x.readlines()
b = len(a)
i = 0

while i < b:
    t = a[i]
    print(t)
    url = t
    
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}
    
    reply_number = urllib.parse.parse_qs(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).query)['reply'][0]

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

    text = soup.select_one('div.ReplyItem:has(a[name="reply{reply_number}"]) .ReplyItem__body, .reply_text div[id$="_{reply_number}"]'.format(reply_number=reply_number)).text.strip()

    print(text)

    i+=1
```

content of document:

https://vk.com/wall-11653786_2058?reply=2059

https://vk.com/wall-11653786_2053?reply=2054

https://vk.com/wall-11653786_2041?reply=2043

error message:

```
File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\soupsieve\css_parser.py", line 1036, in selector_iter
    raise SelectorSyntaxError(msg, self.pattern, index)
soupsieve.util.SelectorSyntaxError: Malformed attribute selector at position 19
  line 1:
--> div.ReplyItem:has(a[name="reply2059
                       ^
    "]) .ReplyItem__body, .reply_text div[id$="_2059
    "]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because your line

```
reply_number = urllib.parse.parse_qs(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).query)['reply'][0]
```

returns the string with the new line character included (e.g. `'2043\n'`). Just strip the `reply_number` and you should be good!

```
# Add .strip() to the end
reply_number = urllib.parse.parse_qs(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).query)['reply'][0].strip()
```